# How to successfully rotate an image in Java without "noises"

Tags: java, image, rotation

I have the following method:

```
private void rotate_image(boolean right) {
    if(image != null) {
        if(right) {
            this.degrees -= 0.005;
        }
        else {
            this.degrees += 0.005;
        }

        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(this.degrees, original_image.getWidth()/2, original_image.getHeight()/2);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
        this.image = op.filter(original_image, null);
    }
}
```

- The image is a Black and White one, meaning its pixels are either 0 or 255.
- The "image" and "original_image" are BufferedImage types.
- I wish to rotate it in small degrees until it reaches a certain position.
- The rotation works fine, BUT... It fills my image with "noises" - pixels that aren't 0 or 255 and that were not present in the original image. So it loses some of its original characteristics.
- As I will need later to analyze every pixel, I would very much appreciate if there is a method in Java that could rotate my image but keeps more of the original aspect.
- These links to the 2 images show well what I mean. It's a pixel grid of a small part of the image before and after rotating:

Image Before: http://s13.postimg.org/3yvak746b/before1.png

Image After: http://s13.postimg.org/b0t86e7s3/after1.png

So, any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance!